# JavaFX Make a transitive pane

Tags: java, javafx-2

Good morning.

I'm doing a program that simulates an adress book in JavaFX. The program is basic to add, modify or delete a contact.

Well, my idea of the program design is to have two panels: one for the table that contains the contacts, and the second panel to modify contacts data.

Well, what I want is that when you open the program, only visible panel containing the table, the other panel, only visible when you want to edit a contact.

It's can possible?

Images:

When run the app:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/roQZo.png

When edit contact:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucVMs.png

FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="1145.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2">
  <!-- TODO Add Nodes -->
  <children>
    <Pane layoutX="0.0" layoutY="0.0" prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="848.0">
      <children>
        <MenuBar layoutX="0.0" layoutY="0.0" prefWidth="848.0">
          <menus>
            <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Archivo">
              <items>
                <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Salir" />
              </items>
            </Menu>
            <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Editar">
              <items>
                <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Modificar" />
                <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Eliminar" />
              </items>
            </Menu>
            <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Acerca">
              <items>
                <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="autor.." />
              </items>
            </Menu>
          </menus>
        </MenuBar>
        <TableView layoutX="0.0" layoutY="24.0" prefHeight="476.0" prefWidth="848.0">
          <columns>
            <TableColumn maxWidth="5000.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="132.0" text="Nombre" />
            <TableColumn maxWidth="5000.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="137.0" text="Apellido" />
            <TableColumn maxWidth="5000.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="108.0" text="F. Nacimiento" />
            <TableColumn maxWidth="5000.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="123.0" text="Telefono" />
            <TableColumn maxWidth="5000.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="146.0" text="email" />
            <TableColumn maxWidth="5000.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="200.0" text="Direccion" />
          </columns>
        </TableView>
      </children>
    </Pane>
    <Pane layoutX="848.0" layoutY="0.0" prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="297.0">
      <children>
        <Label layoutX="17.0" layoutY="38.0" text="Nombre:" />
        <Label layoutX="17.0" layoutY="78.0" text="Apellido:" />
        <Label layoutX="17.0" layoutY="116.0" text="F. Nacimiento:" />
        <Label layoutX="17.0" layoutY="159.0" text="Telefono:" />
        <Label layoutX="17.0" layoutY="205.0" text="Email:" />
        <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="250.0" text="Direccion:" />
        <TextField layoutX="110.0" layoutY="35.0" prefWidth="164.0" />
        <TextField layoutX="110.0" layoutY="75.0" prefWidth="164.0" />
        <TextField layoutX="110.0" layoutY="113.0" prefWidth="164.0" />
        <TextField layoutX="110.0" layoutY="156.0" prefWidth="164.0" />
        <TextField layoutX="110.0" layoutY="202.0" prefWidth="164.0" />
        <TextField layoutX="110.0" layoutY="247.0" prefWidth="164.0" />
        <Button layoutX="17.0" layoutY="309.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="41.9609375" prefWidth="257.0" text="Guardar" />
        <Button layoutX="17.0" layoutY="373.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="41.9609375" prefWidth="257.0" text="Borrar" />
        <Button layoutX="20.0" layoutY="432.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="41.9609375" prefWidth="257.0" text="Cancelar" />
      </children>
    </Pane>
  </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Toggle the `visibleProperty (setVisible(boolean))` and `managedProperty (setManaged(boolean))` (see documentation for this proerty) properties of the `Pane` on the action of the "Edit" MenuItem and "Cancel" Button action event handlers appropriately. To access the pane in event handlers, give the pane a fx:id then inject it to fxml's controller. By the way, it is evening here for me ;).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I see this link and this guy make the same: https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/1437374  Good afternoon, im from Peru :)